# iPhone plist creation from .rtf file

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist, rtf

I have a list of 800 words in an .rtf file in this format:
word1
word2
.
.
word799
word800
Is there any way I can create a plist of Strings out of this? I really do not want to add each word one at a time.
Thanks A Lot!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is copy and paste the list of words into a straight up text file.  Then you can write a command line script in the language of your choice (I'd choose Python, for example) that will read in this text file and invoke the [defaults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defaults_%28software%29) utility from the command line to write your values.  You can use the defaults utility like:

```
$ defaults write $PLIST_FILE $PROPERTY_NAME $VALUE # sets
```